# Why is MOSI pulled low during communication?

Tags: stm32, spi, linux

I am using Allwinner A40i (ARM V7) as SPI master and STM32 as SPI slave. When not communicating with STM32 for SPI, it is correct to use an oscilloscope to capture `MOSI` data, but after STM32 receives the SPI data, `MOSI` is pulled low, lower than `1.6 V`. Therefore, STM32 cannot sample data normally. What is the general reason for this? What are the directions for investigation?
A40i and STM32 are on the same board, and the working voltage of STM32 is `3.3 V`, which is normal. The speed is `10M`. `SPI CLK/CS0/MOSI/MISO` are directly connected, with no other devices connected in between. The working voltage of each SPI pin is `3.3 V`.

Regarding this issue, we made the following attempts:
We are using SPI1 of STM32. When SPI1 and STM32 (STM32A) on the same PCB board, `MOSI`'s level will be pulled down, but we will break the connection of STM32 on the same board, A40i and external external. When the STM32 (STM32B) communication is normal, it is normal. STM32A and STM32B are the same model, but the packaging method is different. We suspect that the power supply voltage of STM32A is unstable, but we grab the voltage waveform with an oscilloscope, which is a stable `3.3V`.

stm32 settings code:

```c
void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 1 */
  hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi2.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi2.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 2 */

}


void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* spiHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(spiHandle->Instance==SPI2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_MspInit 0 */
    /* SPI2 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_SPI2_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**SPI2 GPIO Configuration
    PB13     ------> SPI2_SCK
    PB14     ------> SPI2_MISO
    PB15     ------> SPI2_MOSI
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_15;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* SPI2 DMA Init */
    /* SPI2_TX Init */
    hdma_spi2_tx.Instance = DMA1_Channel3;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_SPI2_TX;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_spi2_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi2_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(spiHandle,hdmatx,hdma_spi2_tx);

    /* SPI2_RX Init */
    hdma_spi2_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel2;
    hdma_spi2_rx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_SPI2_RX;
    hdma_spi2_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_spi2_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_spi2_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_spi2_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi2_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_spi2_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_spi2_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_spi2_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(spiHandle,hdmarx,hdma_spi2_rx);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

uint8_t test_rxbuf[300] = {0xF1, 0xF2, 0xF3, 0xF4, 0xF5, 0xF6, 0xF7, 0xF8, 0xF9, 0xF0};
static inline void Start_SPITransfer(void)
{
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(&hspi2, (INT8U *)test_rxbuf, (INT8U *)test_rxbuf, 256);
}
```

Screenshot of a part of the circuit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Either a hardware or software issue. General procedure is to check everything and so far there is not enough details to give a reasonably short list what to check. Post schematics of the connections and software parts that init the IO pins and SPI peripherals.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community How to put the circuit diagram file in my question?

Comment: @ABeginner - Hi, As shown on the little label next to its name, "Community" is a bot, used for posting automatic messages (e.g. messages caused by the review process). Therefore it cannot reply. However I saw your message:  see [this post](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5710) which explains how to upload an image (typically png or jpg, 2MB maximum size). || Also please clarify the part of your question where you say the SPI signals are using **3.3 V** levels; then you say communication is normal "*where the working voltage of each SPI pin is **1.8 V***". More detail needed. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have connected STM32 output and A7 output together.

When one output sends logic 1 and the other output sends logic 0, that will result into some halfway voltage.

When the two outputs are approximately equally strong the voltage will be approximately half of the supply, which in your case is 1.65V with a 3.3V supply.